# error 1045 (28000) remotely logging into mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

A weird question and i'm unsure what's going on.

I'm connecting to a MySQL database from an apache server using

```
mysql -u username -h 10.0.0.40 -p
Password
```

However when I try to connect using the following, i get the below error

```
mysql -u httpserver -h 10.0.0.40 -p
Password1
ERROR 1045 (28000); Access denied for user 'httpserver'@'10.0.0.10 (using password: YES)
```

(10.0.0.40 being the SQL server)

I don't understand why I can connect with one username/password combo from the same server and not another?

From my `SELECT User,host FROM mysql.user;` I get

```
    User     |      host
httpserver       %
username         %
sqlserver        127.0.0.1
sqlserver        ::1
debian-sys-maint localhost
httpserver       localhost
username         localhost
sqlserver        localhost
```

Any help would be highly appreciated as this has my mind boggled!

Comment: Do you enter the password correctly (I assume so, just checking)?

Comment: It's more than likely that iptables or selinux is blocking the connection from being established. Or the port you're connection is trying to go through is closed.

Comment: Yeah i've tried the password a good few times and its definitely correct, I don't understand why it blocks the `httpserver` user/pass, but not the `username` user/pass combination

Comment: Dillan it's being refused by mysql with that error, not a failing connection

Comment: @Dillan I don't thinks this is a firewall issue, the response from the mysql client is clear, **access denied**. I suppose the password is just not correctly given/set.

Comment: check your /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and if there is a bind-address line, comment it out and restart mysql

Comment: Oh derp. I should probably refrain from posting until I'm actually awake lol

Comment: @flauntster I tried commenting out the bind-address line and still the same issue. 
Dillan It's the thought that counts :p

Comment: I've no idea why it wouldn't accept that username/password. I tried entering it 5 times, I even tried deleting/re-adding the username/password 3 times to make sure it was correct. I've added numerous other shorter usernames/passwords like http/Qwerty99 and it seems to work fine. Oh well!